# Jet engine rotor air outlet reference?

Tags: jet-engine, compressor

I've been given a list of components for a generic jet engine and their properties of interest, mainly rotation speeds and temperatures, and have been tasked to write more complete and unambiguous descriptions for each of them. I have only general knowledge of jet engines and need to understand where in its assembly would be a "rotor air outlet", for which temperature would be reported.  Would this be the outlet from the compressor to the combustor?  Because of the variety of rotors in a jet engine, I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: Rotor just means a disk with rotating blades, there are rotors in the compressors and in the turbines. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I unfortunately do not have more specifics.  My hope was that, knowing that temperature at its outlet is often sensed and reported, this would provide sufficient context to identify the relevant rotor.

Comment: Thank you for the links.  I do not have a temperature sample nor engine family, all I have is a list of named components for a generic jet engine and their properties of interest, mainly rotation speeds and temperatures, and I am trying to more fully and unambiguously describe them.  Because of the variety of rotors in a jet engine, I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: If we narrow it down to either a compressor or turbine rotor, would it help to ask the question this way: If I were interested in knowing how well the engine is performing, which would be of greater interest: the temperature of the gas leaving the compressor or the temperature of the gas leaving the turbine?  Or is there no such distinction?

Comment: "*which would be of greater interest: the temperature of the gas leaving the compressor or the temperature of the gas leaving the turbine?*" The temperature leaving the combustion chamber i.e. entering the turbine. Rising this temperature rises efficiency but it is limited by the thermo-mechanical strength of the turbine's blades. Fancy materials and cooling systems have been developed to increase the strength and therefore the temperature.

Comment: What are the other components you mentioned?  Perhaps we can help you narrow it down by process of elimination with some added context.  And presuming this is a homework assignment?

Comment: This is a work-work user interface-related assignment. :-) And the original authors of the list are unavailable, hence unable to seek clarification from them.  Other components are: burner, compressor, nozzle (exhaust, I assumed), inlet, turbine, shaft (central), exhaust cone, preheater.

Comment: Well, a whole bunch of us know a lot about all the components you mentioned, and can explain in great detail the workings of a jet engine, but without understanding the assignment and desired output better it's really hard to know how to answer this...  If the original authors of the work are unavailable can you ask your customer or boss to identify the specific *need*?

Comment: For example:  "*we need to know the temperature of the air going into the combustion section so that we can program the FADEC to meter the correct amount of fuel...*"  Or something like that.  "Rotor air outlet" just isn't a *normal* term.

Comment: The need is much simpler than that: I need to accurately describe what the temperature being displayed is the temperature of, that's the entirety of it.  Right now it is "The temperature of the rotor air outlet".  I believe you, that it's not a normal term -- I've been able to find sufficient descriptions/explanations for all the other components, just not this one.

Comment: If the ambiguity is unresolvable with this limited information, then I will have to leave it at that.

Comment: "Right now it is "*The temperature of the rotor air outlet*". Not to be snarky, but if it's that simple why isn't this the answer then?  If anyone has an engine with a rotor air outlet it will be immediately clear to them!  Paraphrase, fluff it up a little... i.e. *as the air leaves the rotor the temperature is measured at the outlet and displayed as...*. Otherwise it's still not clear what you really need.

Comment: Its presence in this list was supposed to mean it was applicable to most if not all jet engines, and would be meaningful to most anyone in the field.  I'm not sure what is unclear about what I've sought -- I had hoped that experts in this field would recognize the term and be able to unambiguously identify the engine component that was being referenced, so that someone not in the field would then be able to understand what it refers to.  That is evidently not the case.  My apologies, and thank you all for your time and patience.